# In powershell, using the export-csv cmdlet, is there a way to define the row terminator, as opposed to the standard carriage return?

Tags: powershell

I have fields in the csv files that have carriage returns in them, think emails, and I would like to define a different row terminator if at all possible, thanks!

Comment: How big is the largest CSV file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By convention, a multiline field in a csv field is delimited by double quotes ("). Powershell should do this or you:

```
PS C:\> $ob = new-object PSObject |
    add-member -memberType NoteProperty -name "header" -value "header1" -PassThru |
    add-member -memberType NoteProperty -name "body" -value  @"
Body text
with carriage returns
"@ `
    -PassThru |
    add-member -memberType NoteProperty -name "tail" -value "tail1" -PassThru
PS C:\> $ob

header                                  body                                    tail
------                                  ----                                    ----
header1                                 Body text...                            tail1

PS C:\> $ob | Export-Csv \temp\ml.csv
PS C:\> get-content \temp\ml.csv
#TYPE System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject
"header","body","tail"
"header1","Body text
with carriage returns","tail1"
```

Now importing this file should give you the original:

```
PS C:\> (import-csv C:\Temp\ml.csv).body
Body text
with carriage returns
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't appear like there is. Looking at the code for the command with Reflector it writes the row using the WriteLine method of TextWriter which uses \r\n at the end...

Comment: Aww, that is disappointing...so do you have any suggestions on how to either edit the csv or get around the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution:

```
function Remove-LineBreaks {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [psobject]$InputObject #csv row
        ,
        [Parameter()]
        [string]$Replacement = ''
    )
    process {
        $InputObject | %{$_ -replace "`n", $Replacement}
    }
}

clear-host
$example = 1..3 | %{new-object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
    Index=$_
    Name=("I'm No {0:00}" -f $_)
    Text=@"
this is some multiline text
for item index $_
blah blah blah
"@
}}

write-host 'With Line Breaks' -ForegroundColor Green
$example | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation 
write-host 'Without Line Breaks' -ForegroundColor Green
$example | convertto-csv -NoTypeInformation | Remove-LineBreaks -Replacement '; '
```

You could then convert back to an object, which has had all of its parameters lines removed by adding `| ConvertFrom-CSV` on the end, or can output to file by adding a `| set-content -Path '.\filename.csv'`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can use -Delimiter to categorize row, such as I use comma "," to categorize row..

```
import-csv "C:\Path" -Delimiter ","
```